# Select records in one table depending on data of other table

Tags: mysql

I have a Table with invoices and another table with the payments. The problem is that I need to get all the invoices that are not completely paid (or that it has been paid to much). Here an example of how the table could be:

**tblinvoices**

| InvoiceID | AmountDue |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 2000 |

**tblpaiments**

| InvoiceID | AmountDue | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2021-12-31 |
| 1 | 200 | 2021-11-30 |
| 1 | 300 | 2021-10-31 |
| 2 | 1000 | 2022-01-15 |

Normally I would select all the fields of tblinvoices and the via php check each record if the paiments are ok. But I think it would be faster to select directly the needed rtecors.

I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblpaiments 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblinvoices ON (tblpaiments.InvoiceID = tblinvoices.InvoiceID) 
WHERE tblinvoices.AmmountDue NOT IN (SELECT SUM(tblpaiments.AmmountDue) AS FIELD_1 
                                     FROM tblpaiments)
```

Comment: Yeas, it maybe faster (when you have more records then the records you showed here.  What did you try to get this solved yourself ?   (SO is not a free writing service for code ....)

Comment: Effectively you're right :)

This was my tries, i tried many different things but this was the one that gave me the best result:

SELECT *
FROM
  `tblpaiments`
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN `tblinvoices` ON (`tblpaiments`.`InvoiceID` = `tblinvoices`.`InvoiceID`)
WHERE
  `tblinvoices`.`AmmountDue` NOT IN (SELECT SUM(`tblpaiments`.`AmmountDue`) AS `FIELD_1` FROM `tblpaiments`)

As my tables have different rows I have adapted the code above on my example.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT
    t.InvoiceID, 
    t.AmountDue, 
    SUM(p.AmountDue) Payed,
    t.AmountDue-SUM(p.AmountDue)  NotPayed
FROM tblInvoices t
LEFT JOIN tblpaiments p on p.InvoiceID = t.InvoiceID
GROUP BY t.InvoiceID, t.AmountDue
HAVING AmountDue<>SUM(p.AmountDue)
```

| InvoiceID | AmountDue | Payed | NotPayed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000.00 | 600.00 | 400.00 |
| 2 | 2000.00 | 1000.00 | 1000.00 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ecdabe1c9d204b7e191d1fe4c3f4b87a)

EDIT: Because of "your code shows only invoices for which we received a payment"

```
SELECT
    t.InvoiceID, 
    t.AmountDue, 
    COALESCE(SUM(p.AmountDue),0) Payed,
    t.AmountDue-COALESCE(SUM(p.AmountDue),0)  NotPayed
FROM tblInvoices t
LEFT JOIN tblpaiments p on p.InvoiceID = t.InvoiceID
GROUP BY t.InvoiceID, t.AmountDue
HAVING AmountDue<>SUM(p.AmountDue) OR SUM(p.AmountDue) IS NULL
```

output:
(when a third invoice is added without payments)

| InvoiceID | AmountDue | Payed | NotPayed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000.00 | 600.00 | 400.00 |
| 2 | 2000.00 | 1000.00 | 1000.00 |
| 3 | 3000.00 | 0.00 | 3000.00 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d48ca64ebe0e2aa812c001c78c0858f3)

Comment: Unfortunately I found the problem that blocked me, your code shows only invoices for which we received a payment. If the client has paid nothing the invoice is not displayed, it's for this reason that I searched a solution whit a sub-query.

Comment: I must have missed the missing payments... 

Comment: This time its perfect, now I have to understand the Coalesce command 

Comment: The [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function returns the first argument that  does not have the value NULL.